# Include CSS Media Query in Javascript Event Listener

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have this javascript code that enables the top navigation of my website shrink. See below:

```
<script>
        function init() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
                var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    shrinkOn = 300,
                    header = document.querySelector("header");
                if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                    classie.add(header,"smaller");
                } else {
                    if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                        classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        window.onload = init();
    </script>
```

The code adds the class "smaller" to the header section when the window is scrolled down the specified distance and reduce it when scrolled back up.
However, I want the class to be added and removed only when the screen is larger than 768px (i.e. min-width: 768px). On smaller screen size, I do not want the add and remove class to work.

I saw an example of the code to use but I am not sure how to add it to my code above.

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
  const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 500px
  } else {
    // window width is less than 500px
  }

}
```

Any help on how to combine this will be appreciated.

Comment: You could override the styles of the class that's added within a `max-width` media query, therefore eliminating the need for additional javascript. Or without overriding, you could apply the class styles only within your larger media query i.e `min-width: 768px`

Comment: Thanks James. On closer look, I realized this can be through media query override like you stated.

Answer (score 0):

from what you describe, you're wanting to add your existing code inside the conditional, so:

```
// media query event handler
    if (matchMedia) {
      const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
      mq.addListener(WidthChange);
      WidthChange(mq);
    }

    // media query change
    function WidthChange(mq) {
      if (mq.matches) {
        [[ YOUR CODE ]]
      } else {
       [[ UNBIND SCROLL LISTENER ]] 
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix this by using just media query override like James suggested above rather than adding additional JavaScript codes.